# Recreate AWS amplify application, after amplify delete command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I had several issues while working through this [workshop](https://amplify-workshop.go-aws.com/) including

```
a. AMAZON REKOGNITION not working, 
b. dynamodb tables not updated with images being uploaded.
```

To avoid getting charged for aws resources, I deleted all the AWS resources using `amplify delete` command. If I run the `amplify publish` command, I get the following error:

```
**StackTrace:**
You are not working inside a valid amplify project.
Use 'amplify init' in the root of your app directory to initialize your project with Amplify
Error: You are not working inside a valid amplify project.
```

How can I recreate all the AWS resources without going through the `amplify init` process again?