# Is there an equivalent of "terraform destroy" in AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have created and deployed successfully an Amplify application with:

```
amplify init
amplify add auth
amplify push
```

I would now like to learn the theoretical workflow where I would need to remove the Amplify application with all its resources from AWS and later re-create the app again from checked-in code. Basically, I'd like to `terraform destroy` and `terraform apply` my Amplify project.

After studying all amplify subcommands, I found `amplify remove` and `amplify delete` could be the candidates. `amplify remove` deals with individual resource, `amplify delete` deals with the whole app. But both of them remove resources from the cloud as well as from the local project partially and completely respectively.

I've found a similar unanswered question here [Recreate AWS amplify application, after amplify delete command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045364/recreate-aws-amplify-application-after-amplify-delete-command)

Now I've started to believe that Amplify really lacks support for this workflow which seems to be weird. Could somebody give a confirmation / help?